# How use android intent to find specific email and open it?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have an app where I want to allow users to find specific emails and save information about tham. Then, at a future time, they should be able to open that email again. I don't want to force them to pass the login info to my app, I want to handle it all through intents to the email app already on their device.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't you think it would be a security risk if your app could get a hold of the user's emails?

Comment: @Emmanuel not if you have the proper permission and they allow it.

Comment: Who in their right mind would allow your app to browse their emails?

Comment: @DonRhummy most people will just skip reading your *permissions*. Not safe.

Comment: @Emmanuel all email apps have that permission. And this would be an app that works with emails. I just don't want to force them to have to reenter their login info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No.

There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of email apps for Android. None have to expose any sort of `ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, etc. `Intent` action for you to use. In particular, neither Gmail nor K-9 Mail appear to offer such activities.